# server communication between hardware device and android application

Tags: android

hai friends i am new to android development, i doing an project to communicate android application to GSM based arduino in that the data which is send from the application is stored in free server and gsm board get data and again stored the response to the same server where android app should take response data and display. please help me friends.

Answer (score 0):

You can store response data in shared preference and sqlite.and display the data according to your requirement.please explain briefly which problem you are facing ..